# How to decode JSONP data with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, decode

I have some data that I'm retrieving using JSONP from a remote server. The content contains HTML and I need to make it so the characters render properly instead of printing the tags out. For example, if something has bold tags, it should just appear bold and not have the strong tags around it.

This needs to be done in JavaScript/jQuery. Just about everything I've found in search results uses some type of server side code.

Comment: Erm, what? Any code or something? Your question is difficult to understand and even more difficult to answer at its current state. What is the exact content sent by the server? How are you calling it? What do you want to do with it? What problems are you encountering with your current code (the one you didn't show and which you should have)?

Comment: If you use the right [Ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) it should work properly. Use `.html()` to set the HTML.

Comment: Could you post the exact code you are using to make the call?

Comment: Hope that content from the remote server is sanitized, or that you're planning on ensuring it's safe; watch out for XSS attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP you can understand that you need to wrap you content into a Javascript function such as:

remoteScripts.js:

```
function getContent(){
    return 'YOUR HTML CONTENT';
}
```

and so in your HTML page you can do via JQuery:

```
$('YOUR ELEMENT').html(getContent());
```